# Where are the Origin settings on a Mac?

Tags: macos, origin

I am on a mac and I don't know where the settings are on Origin. I am trying to install The Sims 3 to an external hard drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because pictures say more than a thousand words. I think you can figure out in which directory you want to put your games in :)

[image: How to open preferences: go to Origin in the menu bar and select Preferences or press command-comma]

[image: The location of the installation location by default is /Applications]